# Dijkstra vs A* For Weighted Graph

Tags: algorithm

I'm trying to figure out which algorithm to use to get the least cost path from a given starting node to a goal node.

```
A ----5---- B ---3--- C
|           |
|           /
D ----1-----E ------10------ F
```

I've been looking into both Dijkstra and A* since they both give optimal solutions to such a problem. The way I understand it is that Dijkstra is just A* with a heuristic of 0. I've already implemented Dijkstra's algorithm but was wondering if it's possible to use A* instead. In a very simple graph such as the above (without any other information), is there an admissible heuristic that A* can use to provide even better results compared to Dijkstra or is Dijkstra the most optimal algorithm?

Comment: What kind of "simple graph"? What assumptions do you want to make?

Comment: Exactly like the above. A plain undirected weighted graph with no given assumptions whatsoever.

Comment: There is missing the weights between A-D and B-E without that you can even not know if A* could work.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have any knowledge of an heuristic that fits to the content of the graph then you have to choose Dijkstra.

A* was developed for road maps, where for road distances the constraint applies that the direct distance is always shorter than going via another node. This constraint does not apply for general weighted graphs.

If you don't know such an additional constraint / heuristic of  the content of your graph then   you have to use Dijkstra

Further keep in mind that road map graphs are so huge that it is worth using A*.
If your graph is not huge, then probably it is even not worth thinking whether to find any heuristic. Such a wrong heuristic could even make things worse.

So you could use Dijkstra, and only if you have a performance problem you could start thinking to find a heuristic.